# Rel = translation

Tags: html5, duplicate-content, language, translation, rel

I can't find much online about rel="translation"

We have tutorials and manual entries which we are going to get users to translate.  If the original page in English is:

http://www.scirra.com/tutorial/start

And there are two translations:

http://www.scirra.com/tutorial/es/start (spanish)

http://www.scirra.com/tutorial/de/start (german)

How would I correctly link all these up?  I'm aware at the top of the page I would need to specify the correct IS639-1 code:

```
<html lang="de">
```

But I'm more interested in letting Google know they are not duplicates but are translated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rel=translation has been [proposed](http://www.w3.org/TR/relations) but not adopted by the W3C ([it's not in the HTML5 working document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html)).

If the words on the pages are different then Google won't penalize you for duplicate content (several people say this in the [Webmaster forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters)). There's lots of advice on multi-language sites in [this blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html).

Answer (score 3):

To inform search engines of alternate language versions of a page, you should use the `<link>` element with the `hreflang` attribute, [as described in the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.3.3).

```
<LINK title="The manual in Dutch" rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="http://someplace.com/manual/dutch.html">
```

These links go in the head so are not visible to normal users. For users you can just use normal links in the body. Using `hreflang` might be a good idea though.